# Expected value of maximum function of non-independent random variable

Tags: probability

What would be $E[\max(x, 1-x)]$ where $0< x< 1$?

I used Jensen inequality and have the following steps:

$$\max(x, 1-x) =$$

$$=1-x \text{   if   } x<1/2$$
$$= x \text{   if   } x\geq1/2$$

Then I can integrate the above function over the specified range assuming $x$ is uniformly distributed?

Please advise.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: surely, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct integral is $$\int_0^1 \max(x,1-x)\,dx = \int_0^{1/2} (1-x)\,dx + \int_{1/2}^1 x \,dx $$
$$ = 3/8 + 3/8 = 3/4.$$